# Scipy draw bounding box in image

Tags: opencv, numpy, scipy

I was earlier using `cv.rectangle()` OpenCV methods for drawing bounding box in numpy array and then save it to file. However I have started replacing OpenCV operations with `scipy` and I couldn't find an equivalent methods for this one in `scipy` easily. Is there a way this can be achieved in `scipy`?

Comment: you could try `skimage`

Comment: I dont think skimage have a function for it as well. I ended up using PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.Rectangle function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using simple matrix manipulation operations and replacing the desired rows and columns by the given color as:

```
from scipy.misc import imsave
import numpy as np

# Create 500 x 500 Empty canvas of white color
arr = np.ones((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
color = np.array([0, 255, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
bounding_box = (100, 100, 200, 200)

arr[bounding_box[1], bounding_box[0]:bounding_box[0] + bounding_box[2]] = color
arr[bounding_box[1]:bounding_box[1] + bounding_box[3], bounding_box[0]] = color

arr[bounding_box[1] + bounding_box[3], bounding_box[0]:bounding_box[0] + bounding_box[2]] = color
arr[bounding_box[1]:bounding_box[1] + bounding_box[3], bounding_box[0] + bounding_box[2]] = color

imsave("./debug.png", arr)
```

**Output:**

[image]